# matlab 2014 date functions not found

Tags: matlab, datetime

Trying to help my daughter with matlab 2014 basic. (I have never used it).  In the command window I tried to use the month() functions in various ways that I read in the documentation but matlab returns "month not found"  I tried various datetime functions that appear to be in matlab core and they all failed.  Is there a project library that needs to be added?  Do these functions work in the command line?

Comment: Yes you need the Financial Toolbox to have access to the 'month' function. Typing 'ver' in the command Window will tell you what Toolboxes you have installed on your computer.

Comment: I did see it under financial (which is not installed), however it appeared in Help with MatLab as root.  Are there any datetime functions in root MatLab?

Comment: yes there are a few; look here for a start: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/date.html

Comment: Thanks.  If you make that an answer I mark it +1 accepted.

Comment: Alright thanks I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so to follow up on my comment:

1) You need the Financial Toolbox to have access to the 'month' function. In order to know what is installed on your computer, type `ver` in the Command Window.

2) MATLAB has some builtin functions to play around with dates and times. For example, [date](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/date.html) returns a string containing the current dat in the day-month-year format and [calendar](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/calendar.html) returns an array of double from which you can extract specific dates.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Matlab R2014b, there is a new `datetime` datatype in the core Matlab language. It supports access to calendar fields like month, year, and day, and is supposedly the main date representation in Matlab going forward. You can use this without having to install the Financial Toolbox.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/date-and-time-operations.html

Note that `now()` and `today()` still return datenums; you need to do `datetime('now')` or `datetime('today')` to get equivalent `datetime` values.

All normal Matlab functions and classes can be used from the command line, and anything run on the command line can be called in a script or function. It's the exact same language for both.